# MariaDB, CONNECT engine non-ASCII characters as column names

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to make pivot table using CONNECT engine in MariaDB. If the field values in source table are non-ASCII characters (e.g. 'who','week','你好','Food' 'машина'), I am getting the following CREATE TABLE results:

```
CREATE TABLE `pivex_cn`
( 
`who` varchar(135) NOT NULL, 
`week` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`å•¤é…’` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL `FLAG`=1, 
`Food` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL `FLAG`=1, 
`Ð¼Ð°ÑˆÐ¸Ð½Ð°` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL `FLAG`=1 
) 
ENGINE=CONNECT DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 `TABLE_TYPE`='pivot' `TABNAME`='topivot_cn'
```

If I do then

> SELECT * FROM pivex_cn;

I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1296. Got error 122 'Cannot find matching column' from
>   CONNECT

The source table is also uft8 or uft8mb4, I have tried both..

What can be done about that? Where to look at?

Comment: Have same problem when source column is in Japanese. Still no solutiom for it. If you want to make pivot table, you can connect first and make pivot view in MariaDB